# Multiple criteria conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to do some conditional formatting with multiple points of criteria. I have the first part of the formula done but after that it's beyond me.  `=B2<=B22` is the first cell next to the cell I want to format and references b22 to compare. Works great, however I need a formula that uses b2 through p2 and references the corresponding 22nd row to get the job done.

I have tried `=(b2<=b22,c2<=c22)` along with a variety of other syntax and no luck yet. Please tell me it's a matter of adding more brackets so I can go to bracket town.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
=and(B2<=B22,C2<=C22,D2<=D22,E2<=E22,F2<=F22,G2<=G22,H2<=H22,I2<=I22,J2<=J22,K2<=K22,L2<=L22,M2<=M22,N2<=N22,O2<=O22,P2<=P22)
```

Found the answer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6V3KXEuFZs

Answer (score 0):

Multiple conditions can be joined by AND or OR, as desired:

```
=AND(b2<=b22,c2<=c22)
```

if both conditions must hold.

```
=OR(b2<=b22,c2<=c22)
```

if at least one condition must hold.